# Vim strange ocaml plugin binding even run with --noplugin

Tags: vim, ocaml

While editing ocaml files (*.ml) files, every time I use `<Leader>t` to open CommandT, vim says "No type annotation (.annot) file found". When I use `<Leader>s` to toggle Syntastic, vim go to the interface file of the current file (x.ml to x.mli).

When I run :map, I saw those bindings:

```
x  \t           @<Plug>OCamlPrintType
n  \t           @<Plug>OCamlPrintType                                                            
n  \S           @<Plug>OCamlSwitchNewWin
n  \s           @<Plug>OCamlSwitchEdit
x  \C           @<Plug>BUncomOff
n  \C           @<Plug>LUncomOff
x  \c           @<Plug>BUncomOn
n  \c           @<Plug>LUncomOn
x  <Plug>OCamlPrintType * :<C-U>call Ocaml_print_type("visual")<CR>`<
n  <Plug>OCamlPrintType * :<C-U>call Ocaml_print_type("normal")<CR>
n  <Plug>OCamlSwitchNewWin * :<C-U>call OCaml_switch(1)<CR>
n  <Plug>OCamlSwitchEdit * :<C-U>call OCaml_switch(0)<CR>
```

Then I run `vim --noplugin`, these mappings are still there.
In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ocaml.vim`, I only have one line that sets ocaml indentation so the problem must be somewhere else.
What is creating these bindings? How can I turn them off?

Comment: `:verbose map \t` will tell you where those mappings are set. That's all we can do for you if you don't show us your config.

Comment: @romainl You may check filetype plugins distributed with Vim. These mappings are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--noplugin` does nothing more then setting `noloadplugins` option. And the only thing this option does is disabling loading files from `plugin/` directories from `&runtimepath`.

Thus

1. If these mappings are defined somewhere in `ftplugin/` directory and you have `filetype … on` in your vimrc then `--noplugin` will not prevent them from being loaded. Specifically `<Plug>OCamlPrintType` is defined in `ftplugin/ocaml.vim` *which is distributed with Vim*. You may use

   ```
   echo globpath(&runtimepath, 'ftplugin/ocaml*')
   ```

   to get all places where there is `ocaml` ftplugin. `~/.vim/after` **is not the only place** where ftplugin may be located.
2. If in your vimrc there is `set loadplugins` line then `--noplugin` is completely useless and does not affect anything.
3. It also does not do anything to the stuff stored in `.vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I found this line `if !exists("no_plugin_maps") && !exists("no_ocaml_maps")` in ocaml.vim, so I added `let no_ocaml_maps = 1` in my vimrc and the ocaml mappings are gone now.